# Regex Validation for Dialog Flow Entity name

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dialogflow-es

I am trying to write regular expression for validating name that can be used as entity name.

Criteria : Entity name may contain only the following: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ (underscore), - (dash). And it should start with a letter.

This is my Python code for the same(which is not correct)

```
import re
from random import randint

entityName = 'Enity Demo-trial'

if re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z][[_|a-zA-Z|0-9|-]*]+",entityName):

    print("Validation failed")

else:

    print("Validation satisfied")
```

Comment: For string `Enity Demo-trial`, do you want to match `Enity` and therefore print validation failed?

Comment: Poor choice of conditional statements if you ask me, would have made more sense putting them the other way around :P

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z][\w\-]*` will work for you.

You don't need to include all those OR operators "`|`" inside a character class.

Comment: No need to escape the `-` at end of character set

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew maybe I'm confusing it with `Regex.IsMatch` for C#? I could have sworn `re.match` was the python version of that.

Comment: My mistake, it seems that re.match returns a match object as well, but match objects are always considered true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if re.search(r"(?i)^[a-z][a-z\d_-]*$", subject):
    print("Validation satisfied")
else:
    print("Validation failed")
```